# Smtp send email with another address

Tags: email, smtp, smtp-auth

Hi all I have a site where if i want to send an email I have to set the smtp with this configuration:
Enable Advanced Smtp    **Yes**
Auth Mode       **Login**
Username        **noreply@myserver.com**
Password        **password**
Smtp host       **smtp.myserver.com**
Smtp port       **465** 
Use SSL                 **Yes**

If I want to send with my smtp settings mail from another address like test@test.it how can I do that? Because my client don't want to see my domain when receive the email but another email.
Is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is an SMTP server with relaying. if smtp.myserver.com has relaying, than you can use a variety of languages.  YOu need to modify the >MAIL From:  parameter in any which of those languages.

For magento, modify: “/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email.php"

then under the 
public function send() function you need to modify:

```
    ->setFrom($this->getFromEmail(), $this->getFromName())
```

and use

```
   ->setFrom("test@test.com")
```

Comment: how can I know if my server is relaying with other?

Comment: Most support it by default, Do some testing prior to deployment. Since you're logging with username and password, you're an authenticated user. Most smtp servers i've seen restrict anonymous relays, but it's evidently not anonymous with your username and password.

Comment: ok than instead of my email data I can se into username test@test.it and its password right?

Comment: username is different than your from name. you need your username and password to initially authenticate. BUt once it's authenticated you can compose the e-mail with the from and from display parameters to change it to something different.

Comment: uhm.. I don't have this settings, I'm using Magento with an extension I have to search it inside its code

Comment: i've modified the answer, with Magento see the Email.php and modify the send() function to modify the ->setFrom function.

Comment: If I'm using an extension like AdvancedSmtp and set its value doesn't send with the email that I want. Have you tried?